# Can multiple administrator servers exist in single domain of Weblogic server

Tags: weblogic

Can anyone tell me that whether there can be multiple administrator servers can exist in single Weblogic domain or not?  If yes then how the managed server decides which administrator server is used for startup confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is definitely NO. There is exactly one admin server per domain.